# select() not working as it should, where is the bug?

Tags: c, linux, select

Given the following code, the expectation is for there to be a one-second sleep each time `select()` is called. However, the sleep only occurs on the first call and all subsequent calls result in no delay:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = 1;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        /* Sleep for one second */
        int result=select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);
        printf("select returned: %d\n",result);
    }
}
```

Why do all calls to `select()` except the first return immediately?

Compiler: gcc 4.9.2

OS: Centos 7 (Linux)

Kernel info: 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64

Comment: Better use [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) for that case. BTW, prefer [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) to the old `select`

Answer (score 6):

From the man page:

> On Linux, select() modifies timeout to reflect the amount of  time  not
>          slept

So, set `tv` [in the loop] before calling `select`

Answer (score 5):

As stated in [the manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)

> On Linux, select() modifies timeout to reflect the amount of time not
>          slept; most other implementations do not do this.  (POSIX.1 permits
>          either behavior.)  This causes problems both when Linux code which
>          reads timeout is ported to other operating systems, and when code is
>          ported to Linux that reuses a struct timeval for multiple select()s
>          in a loop without reinitializing it.  Consider timeout to be unde‐
>          fined after select() returns.

As the first run ended by timeout, the tv value is reset to 0 seconds. Solution: reinitialize tv on every run.